# How do I write a OrderBy query when setting up a trigger between Zapier and FireStore Collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

As the title states, I am trying to connect my Firestore collection to my Zapier with a trigger. I am confused about how I should write the query though.

[image: Zapier Screen Shot]

I understand I need to write an orderby query but I don't understand how I should write it. Here is my collection.

[image: Fire Store Collection Screenshot]

I added the Time Object to be used by OrderBy, but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you are looking for looks like this:

```
"orderBy": [{
    "field": {
        "fieldPath": "Time"
    },
    "direction": "DESCENDING"
}]
```